# Button opening activity specific

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I will make this as specific as possible. I have a Button. This button is called 'Send'. When a user clicks the Button 'Send', I want my app to automatically send the email into my inbox. The problem is, Every time i ask this question, People here tell me, to 'Choose an Email Client'. I do not want this. Here is a scenario, A user types 'HIS' email into the first box. Then puts 'TEXT' in the box below. When this user clicks 'SEND' The app should automatically send that information to MY email inbox.

My EmailActivity.java is below..

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.ComponentName;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class EmailActivity extends Activity {
    ;

    Button buttonSend;
    EditText textTo;
    EditText textSubject;
    EditText textMessage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.email_layout);



    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    textTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTo);
    textSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
    textMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);

    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto","r2kbeastgaming4us.com", null));

            String to = textTo.getText().toString();
            String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
            String message = textMessage.getText().toString();

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
            //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
            //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

            //need this to prompts email client only
            email.setType("message/rfc822");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

        }
    });
}
```

}

And my email_layout is below..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewPhoneNo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

    <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewSubject"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Subject : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSubject"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Message : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: for that you have to send those information to a web service and that will send email to that account

Comment: @VivekMishra How would I Accomplish this? Is there anywhere you can link me?

Comment: you have to consult backend developers like php etc. regarding this

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly call gmail from your app, for this you have to mention package name.Try this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto","r2kbeastgaming4us.com", null));

            String to = textTo.getText().toString();
            String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
            String message = textMessage.getText().toString();

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
            //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
            //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

            //need this to prompts email client only
            email.setType("message/rfc822");

          **email.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");**

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```